# asp.net core - long running process polling other bounded contexts events outbox

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, ihostedservice

I'm building an app folowing DDD paterns with each AR having their events outbox saved to a permanent store.
That store gets polled by other parts interested in events.

Whole application is user oriented so the basic infrastructure is asp.net web api.

Now, i'd like to avoid having my domain artifacts spread across different processes/infrastructure options. For example, Azure Function that listens for event store & does logic upon events received.

It seems convenient to have web api & events consumer together in same container. Reason is that domain artifacts are deployed together with api & events consumer infrastructure.

I read that `IHostedService` might be one option for it as it can run as long running background process.

Question is, is `IHostedService` meant for this particular scenario of reacting to event outboxes? or are there some important drawbacks i'm missing and  better infrastructural choices?

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't think there is anything wrong with using *hosted service* for running background workers.

I'm more sceptical about the ***"polling from other bounded contexts"*** part. I'd be at least concerned if that breaks the encapsulation of my contexts (similar to having "foreign" components read from a contexts persistence). But this might not be the case in your situation.

Anyways, in case you just want to guarantee that your events are reliably transmitted I would rather make sure that each component realizing a specific bounded context (e.g. microservice or component of a monolith) ***pushes*** these events somewhere interested consumer are able to pick them up.

So if it is about the reliable transmission of outgoing events I would suggest the ***[transactional outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html)***, maybe in combination with a [publish-subscribe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) approach.

As you're on the .net stack the [outbox feature of NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/) might be interesting for you.

Comment: you're right about violating encapsulation but lets leave that part aside for the moment. just  to clarify, are you saying that `IHostedService` is not tied to asp.net core  web api idle, recycle, etc...? or you mean its irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#:%7E:text=The%20IHostedService%20interface%20provides%20a,NET%20Core%202.1%20with%20IHost%20).) about implementing an IHostedService.

Indeed, IHostedService is a good way for long running process for your scenario by two methods.
It is important to note that the way you deploy your ASP.NET Core WebHost or .NET Host might impact the final solution. For instance, if you deploy your WebHost on IIS or a regular Azure App Service, your host can be shut down because of app pool recycles. But if you are deploying your host as a container into an orchestrator like Kubernetes, you can control the assured number of live instances of your host. In addition, you could consider other approaches in the cloud especially made for these scenarios, like Azure Functions. Finally, if you need the service to be running all the time and are deploying on a Windows Server you could use a Windows Service.

But even for a WebHost deployed into an app pool, there are scenarios like repopulating or flushing application's in-memory cache that would be still applicable.

The IHostedService interface provides a convenient way to start background tasks in an ASP.NET Core web application (in .NET Core 2.0 and later versions) or in any process/host (starting in .NET Core 2.1 with IHost). Its main benefit is the opportunity you get with the graceful cancellation to clean-up the code of your background tasks when the host itself is shutting down.

Comment: wouldn't *Always On* feature on App Service solve web app going down/recycle/idle?

Comment: In general only if u meet some unstable states like leading app crashes, hangs or memory leaks which will make app going recycle.